# MATLAB creating chart with two x-axes: how to align them?

Tags: matlab, graph, charts, alignment, axis

I'm trying to plot a function using two different x-axes. As you can see in the image, the axes are not overlapping properly!

How do I fix it? I've already set it up to have the same number of ticks on both axes but it didn't help!

[image: Axes are not aligned: look at the intersections!]

This is the code I'm using:

```
ax1 = gca;
set(gca, 'box', 'off')
xlabel('Frequency shift, \Delta\omega (/THz)');
ylabel('Autocorrelation, F_{2}');
ylim([0.0,1]);
xlim([0, 10])

xlimits = get(ax1,'XLim');
ylimits = get(ax1,'YLim');
xinc = (xlimits(2)-xlimits(1))/5;
yinc = (ylimits(2)-ylimits(1))/5;
set(ax1,'XTick',[xlimits(1):xinc:xlimits(2)],...
        'YTick',[ylimits(1):yinc:ylimits(2)])

ax1.XColor = 'b';
ax1.YColor = 'b';
ax1_pos =  ax1.Position;

ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,...
    'XAxisLocation','top',...
    'YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Color','none');
ax2 = gca;
xlim([0, 2.5]) %in nm (note two pi)
ylim([0.0,1]);

xlimits = get(ax2,'XLim');
ylimits = get(ax2,'YLim');
xinc = (xlimits(2)-xlimits(1))/5;
yinc = (ylimits(2)-ylimits(1))/5;
set(ax2,'XTick',[xlimits(1):xinc:xlimits(2)],...
        'YTick',[ylimits(1):yinc:ylimits(2)])

xlabel('Wavelength shift, \Delta\omega(/nm)');
ylabel('Autocorrelation, F_{2}');

ax2 = gca;
%set(ax,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','off')
ax2.FontSize = 15;
ax2.Box = 'on';
ax2.LineWidth = 2;
set(gca, 'box', 'off')


set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'FontSize',15);
```

Comment: Also, I don't know why the upper x-axis label gets cropped when I save the image! It should read "Wavelength"...

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe

```
ax1_pos = get(gca,'Position');
ax2 = axes('Position', [ax1_pos(1) (ax1_pos(2) - 0.5) ax1_pos(3) ax1_pos(4)]);
```

Comment: You're right - your suggestion definitely moves the axes around but they're "smaller" than the principal ones...so moving doesn't do the trick...somehow I need to enlarge them, too!

Comment: well this is another issue, try to change the width ax2.LineWidth = 1.5

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the x-axis but the y-axis is still too short :'(